# How to sync branch merging via pull request on Visual Studio Team Services with Visual Studio Desktop

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, branching-and-merging

I cannot make branch merges completed in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) web interface show in Visual Studio 2017 Desktop (VS).

Details: 
I created a test project with Git support in VSTS and cloned it in VS. In VS Team Explorer, the master branch showed correctly. In VSTS, I created a user story and then created a branch from master (via the User Story dialog). I could make the new branch show in VS when doing sync/fetch on master in VS Team Explorer. I checked out the branc in VS, made a change to a file, and committed and pushed. The change showed up correctly in VSTS. There, I created a pull request of the branch into master with me as reviewer and approved it. This merged the branch on VSTS and deleted it, at least the Branches view no longer showed the branch, only master, and the merge history looked correct. Now I want to pull that merge in VS, where both master and branch are still showing both in the local repo and under remotes/origin. A checkout/sync on master does reflect the changed file, but the branch is still visible in remote/origin, even though it is gone in VSTS! How do I make VS sync here so the branch no longer shows?

Or am I getting the workflow wrong? Again, what I am doing is

1. User Story (VSTS) ->
2. branch (VSTS) ->
3. sync (VS) checkout branch (VS) ->
4. change files (VS) ->
5. commit/push (VS) ->
6. pull request (VSTS) ->
7. merge (VSTS) ->
8. ??? (VS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`git fetch -p`** command directly to sync remote branches with origin/branches.

`-p` (`--prune`) option for `git fetch` will remove the no longer existing branches before fetching. So you can go to the root directory of the local repo and execute `git fetch -p`, then you will find the merged branch won’t show under `remotes/origin`.

---

Let the developers be informed if there have merging, you can use below options:

#### Option 1: add notifications when PR is completed

You can add a subscription in VSTS notifications page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_notifications?view=contents), specify the email addresses you want to inform and filter the PR status changes to completed, so that the developers can know when a branch has been merged.

[image]

**Note:** for multiple email addresses,you can separate with comma.

#### Option 2: get updates manually

If you don’t want to set notifications for the developers, they should view the changes by:

- go to the VSTS web page directly
- or use `git fetch -p` and `git branch -a` to update their local repo, and check if there has deleted branch(es).

Comment: Thanks Marina, I opened a cmd prompt from VS in the local root, executed `git fetch -p` and the remote merged branch disappeared from the VS view. As @Matt above explained the local branch tracks the remote branch, so I guess generically in a situation where pruning removes a branch from the remote view a careful review is necessary. Also like I asked Matt above, what is the Git mechanism (and the VS/VSTS realization of it) to make the developers aware that a particular branch on the remote was merged into its parent and deleted?

Comment: It seems odd that MS wouldn't have provided a button shortcut to `git fetch -p`...

Comment: All the changed are record by commits, so git can detected if there has changes by comparing the HEAD of a branch. And `git branch -a` can list all the remote branches, so it's easy to only fetch the existing remote branches.

Comment: For most of git GUIs, they only list the commands with default options. Because there are manly options for a git command. Such as for git fetch, it not only with the option -p, but also for the options like -f (--force), --dry-run, --append etc.

Comment: So does a developer always have to do a `git branch -a` and to find whether the branch they may are still working on or have at least locally available is is still live? Isn't there a canonical git mechanism to keep developers informed of merges? And if so how is it mapped to VSTS/VS?

Comment: You can set notifications for the developers so that they can be informed the mergeds. Else, they should find the updates manually by themselves. I added the part in my answer, you can find details in the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The whole "sync" process in VS is likely where you're getting confused, because it hides the details of what Git is actually doing.

"Sync" will never delete any of your local branches, because you might have more not-yet-pushed changes on your local branch that would be wiped out if it did that automatically.

Local branches have a concept of "tracking" a remote branch. What you're seeing is occurring because your local `mybranch` is still tracking a remote branch called `origin/mybranch`, even though that doesn't currently exist on VSTS. If you were to do a `push` of your local `mybranch` right now, the remote tracking branch would be automatically (re-)created, and its contents would match what you have locally.

In summary: you shouldn't expect "sync" to delete a branch, because that's not how it works. You need to delete it manually.

Comment: Thanks Matt - makes sense. So are you saying if I deleted the local branch, the remote tracked branch would disappear from the VS branch view? In general, what is the Git mechanism (and the VS/VSTS realization of it) to make the developers aware that a particular branch on the remote was merged into its parent and deleted?

Comment: One thing to note: even you delete the local branches, the tracking branch still exist under remotes/origin unless use `git fetch -p` to remove it.

Comment: Yep, you can prune as Marina mentioned, which will remove your local if you've already deleted the remote branch via the merge/PR completion process. If you just delete your local branch without deleting it on the remote, nothing will happen up on VSTS. You could use the `git branch :remotebranchname` command to directly delete the remote branch if you wanted. But nothing in VS is going to keep a remote and local branch's existence in sync. It's a failure of the "sync" abstraction - Git is decentralised. The term "Sync" is misleading. It's trying to force another concept on top of git.

Comment: In practice you end up with dead/old branches galore on your local repository. But a branch isn't a copy of code or files, it's just a pointer to a point in time of the commit history, which is quite different to how it used to work in TFVC. I wouldn't worry too much about those leftover branches, or if it does concern you, just prune every few weeks.